# iOS Can't update Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode

So I've just updated Xcode via the Mac AppStore to version 7.1

[image]

However when I run the application it is using version 7.0 (without iOS 9.1)

[image]

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: see if you have two xcodes installed in your mac. A restart after xcode upgrade is necessary.

Comment: same issue here with Xcode 7.1 and 7.2. good job Apple.

Comment: Same with 7.2 and 7.3... Just Works™

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while trying to update to 7.1. Manually deleting Xcode & restarting my laptop solved the problem, even though I had only one copy of Xcode on my mac.

Comment: deleting Xcode and just restarting ? or installing it again ?

Comment: I'm not sure what caused the issue on my mac, but deleting the current version 7.0, restarting and then cleanly installing 7.1 via App Store worked for me.

Comment: I'm doing the same hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to uninstall the xcode and reinstall it. Download the latest version xcode from apple developer account website.. not from appstore

Answer (score 1):

Fixing ownership for the whole application worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Applications/Xcode.app
```